# SQL calculate time difference between two rows that contain 2 specific values only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains status updates about users on a mobile device; every time they change status or their position is updated, a new row is created:

```
view_id  time_stamp           user           issue_event       original_value   new_value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6040462  2017-03-20 02:00:43  DerekRoberts   Position updated  NULL             NULL
6040461  2017-03-20 02:04:01  JamesMorrison  state changed     Active           Paused
6040461  2017-03-20 02:08:33  JamesMorrison  Position updated  NULL             NULL
6040462  2017-03-20 02:20:42  DerekRoberts   Position updated  NULL             NULL
6040462  2017-03-20 02:32:29  DerekRoberts   state changed     Active           Paused
6040461  2017-03-20 02:34:11  JamesMorrison  state changed     Paused           Active
6040461  2017-03-20 02:36:22  JamesMorrison  Position updated  NULL             NULL
6040462  2017-03-20 02:52:47  DerekRoberts   Position updated  NULL             NULL
6040462  2017-03-20 03:01:03  DerekRoberts   state changed     Paused           Active
```

What I am trying to do is find out the length of time each user remains in the 'Paused' state for... so that's the difference in time between the 'Paused' value and the 'Active' value in the [new_value] column.  for each user.

I thought I could use LEAD() to find the next row for each user, but the 'Active' that marks the end of their paused time is rarely the next row... it could be any number of rows further down the table.

So far, my query looks like this:

```
;WITH UserPauseActivity AS
(SELECT [new_value],
 ShiftDate = CAST([time_stamp] as DATE),
 PauseStartUser = [user],
 PauseEndUser = LEAD([user], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [user], [time_stamp]),
 PauseStart = [time_stamp],
 PauseEnd = LEAD([time_stamp], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [user], [time_stamp]),
 PauseStartDate = CAST([time_stamp] AS DATE),
 PauseEndDate = CAST(LEAD([time_stamp], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [user], [time_stamp]) AS DATE)
FROM [SAFE].[dbo].[cc_shift_log_view])

SELECT PauseStartUser [user],
ShiftDate,
PauseStart,
PauseEnd,
DATEDIFF(minute, PauseStart, PauseEnd) IdleTime
FROM UserPauseActivity
WHERE [new_value] = 'Paused'
AND PauseEnd IS NOT NULL
AND PauseStartUser = PauseEndUser
AND PauseStartDate = PauseEndDate
AND PauseStartDate >= '2017-03-20 00:00:00' and PauseStartDate <= '2017-03-21 23:59:59'
ORDER BY ShiftDate, [user]
```

Which returns this:

```
user             ShiftDate    PauseStart           PauseEnd              IdleTime
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JamesMorrison    2017-03-20   2017-03-20 02:04:01  2017-03-20 02:08:33   4
DerekRoberts     2017-03-20   2017-03-20 02:32:29  2017-03-20 02:52:47   20
```

The PauseStart value is correct, but the PauseEnd is not right, being the next row in the table for that user, rather than the next row contining the corresponding 'Active' value which would mark the actual end of their paused duration, so any help in figuring this out would be much appreciated!

I'm using MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: do you need multiple rows for a user if there are multiple pauses?

Comment: I think you can use LEAD if you WHERE and ORDER your subquery properly. It is possible to have only the next row be the right one with enough filtering and ordering.

Comment: In short - yes. It should be impossible for there to be two consecutive pauses without a corresponding Active; on their devices they would select pause, and the only option for them from the paused state is back to active. So there will always be an 'Active' after every 'Paused', even if it's hours later.

Comment: Each user will have exactly one status change from active -> paused and paused -> active as in example or it will be more?

Comment: that's what i meant..if there are multiple such occurrences (Pause-->Active)for a user..do you have to return all of them?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean... there could be multiple changes from paused back to active, and yes, I'd want to return all of them with the calculated duration between each occurance.

Comment: If it's impossible to have multiple consecutive pause, how could there be multiple consecutive actives?

Comment: For each individual user, there can only be a 'Paused' followed by an 'Active', then followed by another 'Paused' and then another 'Active', and so on. There may be consecutive 'Active's in the table, but they'll be from different users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that the only state change possible is from Active -> Paused -> Active..., you can use `lead` to get the desired result.

```
select usr,shiftDate,pause_start,pause_end,datediff(second,pause_start,pause_end)/60.0 as idleTime
from (select usr,cast(time_stamp as date) as shiftDate,time_stamp as pause_start
      ,lead(time_stamp) over(partition by usr order by time_stamp) as pause_end
      ,original_value,new_value
      from t
      where issue_event='state changed'
     ) t 
where original_value='Active' and new_value='Paused'
```

Comment: That's perfect! Exactly what I was trying to achieve... many thanks indeed! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot and get this result assuming you will have only one Change from active to pause and pause to active as below:

```
select view_id, [user], [1] as [PauseStart], [2] as [PauseEnd], IdleTime = Datediff(MINUTE, [1],[2]) from (
select view_id, time_stamp, [user], RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by [user] order by time_stamp) from #youruser 
where issue_event = 'state changed   '
) a
pivot (max(time_stamp) for RowN in ([1],[2])) p
```

Output:

```
+---------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
| view_id |     user      |       PauseStart        |        PauseEnd         | IdleTime |
+---------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
| 6040462 | DerekRoberts  | 2017-03-20 02:32:29.000 | 2017-03-20 03:01:03.000 |       29 |
| 6040461 | JamesMorrison | 2017-03-20 02:04:01.000 | 2017-03-20 02:34:11.000 |       30 |
+---------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is an OUTER APPLY with a sub query (example below). Change the OUTER APPLY to a CROSS APPLY if you don't want to catch pauses that have not finished.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
    view_id int,
    time_stamp DateTime,
    [user] nvarchar(50),
    issue_event nvarchar(50),
    original_value nvarchar(30),
    new_value nvarchar(40))

INSERT INTO #Table
VALUES
(6040462,'2017-03-20 02:00:43','DerekRoberts','Position updated',NULL,NULL)
,(6040461,'2017-03-20 02:04:01','JamesMorrison','state changed','Active','Paused')
,(6040461,'2017-03-20 02:08:33','JamesMorrison','Position updated',NULL,NULL)
,(6040462,'2017-03-20 02:20:42','DerekRoberts','Position updated',NULL,NULL)
,(6040462,'2017-03-20 02:32:29','DerekRoberts','state changed','Active','Paused')
,(6040461,'2017-03-20 02:34:11','JamesMorrison','state changed','Paused','Active')
,(6040461,'2017-03-20 02:36:22','JamesMorrison','Position updated',NULL,NULL)
,(6040462,'2017-03-20 02:52:47','DerekRoberts','Position updated',NULL,NULL)
,(6040462,'2017-03-20 03:01:03','DerekRoberts','state changed','Paused','Active')
,(6040462,'2017-03-21 03:32:29','DerekRoberts','state changed','Active','Paused')
,(6040462,'2017-03-21 04:05:03','DerekRoberts','state changed','Paused','Active')
,(6040461,'2017-03-22 02:04:01','JamesMorrison','state changed','Active','Paused')


SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Table

SELECT
    [user], 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(10), pausedEvent.time_stamp, 102) ShiftDate, 
    pausedEvent.time_stamp PauseStart,
    activatedEvent.time_stamp PauseEnd,
    DATEDIFF(minute, pausedEvent.time_stamp, activatedEvent.time_stamp) IdleTime
FROM
    #Table pausedEvent   
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 
            activatedEvent.time_stamp
        FROM 
            #Table activatedEvent
        WHERE 
            activatedEvent.issue_event = 'state changed'
            and activatedEvent.original_value = 'Paused'
            and activatedEvent.new_value = 'Active'
            and activatedEvent.time_stamp > pausedEvent.time_stamp
            and activatedEvent.[user] = pausedEvent.[user]
        ORDER BY time_stamp
    ) activatedEvent
WHERE
    pausedEvent.issue_event = 'state changed'
    and pausedEvent.original_value = 'Active'
    and pausedEvent.new_value = 'Paused'

DROP TABLE #Table
```

Note the performance of the various options may vary depending upon the indexes that are available (I'm not sure how fast this would be).